# Laravel - loop on array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I have statement like this :

```
result:
0:{
    commentContent:"foo"
}
1:{
    commentContent:"bar"
}
```

I want to add number of result array to commentContent. Here is what I want :

```
result:
0:{
    commentContent:"foo0"
}
1:{
    commentContent:"bar1"
}
```

At this moment, here is I have : (Literally it's not correct)

```
$commentList[0]['commentContent'] = $commentList[0]['commentContent']+'0';
$commentList[1]['commentContent'] = $commentList[1]['commentContent']+'1';
```

How to do this in Laravel controller with foreach?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .(dot) in php to concatenate:

```
$commentList[0]['commentContent'] = $commentList[0]['commentContent'].'0';
$commentList[1]['commentContent'] = $commentList[1]['commentContent'].'1';
```

OR

```
$commentList[0]['commentContent'] .= '0';
$commentList[1]['commentContent'] .= '1';
```

Using foreach loop:

```
foreach ($comment_list as $key=>$val) {
    $comment_list[$key]['commentContent'] = $val['commentContent'] . $key;
}
```

Comment: I want create it with foreach or for.

Answer (score 0):

Use usual foreach and append key to strings

```
foreach ($commentList as $k => &$i) 
    $i['commentContent'] = $i['commentContent'] . $k;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
$result = [
            0 => [
                'commentContent' => 'foo'
            ],
            1 => [
                'commentContent' => 'bar'
            ]
        ];

        foreach ($result as $index => &$array) {
            foreach ($array as &$value) {
                $value .= $index;
            }
        }
        var_dump($result);
```

This would print:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'commentContent' => string 'foo0' (length=4)
  1 => &
    array (size=1)
      'commentContent' => &string 'bar1' (length=4)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think a cleaner approach would be to do it using laravel's collection.

```
$result = [
    0 => [
        'commentContent' => 'foo'
    ],
    1 => [
        'commentContent' => 'bar'
    ]
];

$updatedResult = collect($result)->map(function ($value, $key) {
    return $value['commentContent'] . $key;
});
```

For more information check out the doc.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections